# Constructing a JPEG image from byte array

Tags: php, image, arduino, jpeg

I'm trying to construct a JPEG image from a byte string using PHP. I understand the base64 decode and encoding part, but right now part of my data looks like this:

```
FF D8 FF FE 0 24 65 0 EF 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 F0 0 40 1 B 0 32 12 B 51 4 51 4 0 0 FF DB 0 84 0 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 7 4 4 4 4 4 8 6 6 5 7 A 9 A A A 9 A 9 B C 10 D B C F C 9 A E 13 E F 10 11 12 12 12 B D 13 15 13 11 15 10 11 12 11 1 3 3 3 4 4 4 8 4 4 8 11 B 46 15 73 95 5C 12 7 5A E3 75 82 9A C3 67 D7 6A 90 8A 1B 78 A 88 5B 30 CE B8 F4 3F CC 36 54 E5 0 C5 AC AF D4 B0 2B 45 A3 D3 CA 29 8F 77 AD D6 C9 13 B3 A6 2F FC....
```

I know for a fact that it's a jpg coming from a arduino camera, sent using a POST request to my PHP script, and that FF D8 marks the start of a JPG but that's all I know.

My question is given this string, how to do convert it to base64 or a proper jpg image which I can upload using PHP?

edit: I tried decoding an actual jpg file using file_get_contents("temp.jpg") and I got this:

```
137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10 0 0 0 13 73 72 68 82 0 0 0 200 0 0 0 200 8 6 0 0 0 173 88 174 158 0 0 32 0 73 68 65 84 120 94 237 157 7 92 20 199 23 199 127 32 216 197 130 40 216 187 216 131 93 99 47 81 35 118 141 189 197....
```

Close but not exactly the same format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, although I cannot test them at the moment to see what may work.

1. The [`hex2bin`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) function is available in PHP ≥ 5.4.0 and converts hex to a binary string. Do note, however, that you'll probably have to remove the spaces from the string prior to converting.
2. If you're running a lower PHP version, you can use [`pack('H*', $string)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) instead to achieve the same results. Again, no spaces.
3. The binary string you obtain by using either of the above methods can be converted to base64 by using [`base64_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).
4. Finally, [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) should work on base64 data, if my memory serves me correctly.

No guarantee that any of these will work, since I can't check at the moment, but there are no other answers so hopefully it helps. Good luck!